# ASP.NET Core API sending string wrapped in double quotes

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

My ASP.NET Core API generates a `SAS` for a file to be uploaded to Azure Blob Storage. Looks like the string is being wrapped in double quotes and this is creating a problem with the front end solution I'm using to upload files.

How can I return a string but make sure that it's not wrapped in double quotes?

This is the API controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetSAS(string blobUri, string _method)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(blobUri) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(_method))
       return new StatusCodeResult(400);

    // Get SAS
    var sas = _fileServices.GetSAS(blobUri, _method);

    return Ok(sas);
}
```

Comment: Show us the code you have now, we can't help otherwise.

Comment: What does your controller method look like?  ASP.NET core shouldn't wrap in double quotes by default but it sounds like your response is getting formatted as JSON somehow.

Comment: What is the type of `sas`? string?

Comment: Just posted the API method. At the top of my API controller, I do have `[Produces("application/json")]` which explains why it's a `JSON`

Comment: @DavidG Yes, SAS is string but my API controller is producing JSON

Comment: This is the only method that is supposed to return `string` in my controller. How can I override `[Produces("application/json")]` only for that method?

Comment: Sorry, just corrected my typo. This method is the only one that is supposed to return `string`. All the others need to return `JSON`. So, I need to override this setting only for this particular method.

Comment: Add `[Produces(".....")]` to the action.

Comment: Thank you! I needed to use `[Produces("text/plain")]`. Please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks again!

Comment: Just remove ```[Produces("application/json")]```, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73806345/9258504

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As discussed in the comments you have a `[Produces]` attribute on the class that is forcing a JSON response. From the [docs on `ProducesAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.producesattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.0) we can see it can be applied to an action as well as the controller. So, you can override for a particular action by adding it there, in your case you need [text/plain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types):

```
[Produces("text/plain")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetSAS(string blobUri, string _method)
{
    //snip
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're returning an `OkResult`, which will serialize the object passed into it. Since that object is a string, and since the default serializer is JSON, your response ends up as a *JSON string*, i.e. with double quotes around it.

To fix this, you can take a number of different paths. First, you can simply change the return type to `string`. That will cause a `ContentResult` to be wrapped around it, which will not result in serialization. For example:

```
public async Task<string> GetSAS(string blobUri, string _method)
{
    ...

    return sas;
}
```

Second, you can use the `Produces` attribute to dictate the return content type as `text/plain`.

```
[Produces("text/plain")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetSAS(string blobUri, string _method)
```

Lastly, you can simply leave it as-is, and instead interpret the result correctly as JSON on the client-side. You can use `JSON.parse` in your JavaScript code to get the string value:

```
var sas = JSON.parse(result);
```

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you! Because @DavidG spent time helping me, I picked his as the answer but at least wanted to thank you for the great explanation!

Comment: Sure. No problem. I figured as much. I just wanted to add the explanation and some alternative ways to solve the issue for posterity.

Comment: @Sam It's not about time, it's about the right answer - this one is clearly more detailed, I'd be happy if you switched it.

Comment: I think I'll let the great people of SO and history decide :-) Thank you both very much!